# Regular expression search and replace in Sublime Text

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext2

I have an array in Sublime Text with every city in the U.S as the value and a code which includes the state abbreviation as the key.  It looks a little something like this:

```
$array = array(
  "United States of America" => array(
        "USAK0001" => "Adak",
        "USAK0002" => "Adak Island",
        "USAK0003" => "Akiachak",
        "USAK0004" => "Akiak",
        "USAK0005" => "Akutan",
        "USAK0006" => "Alakanuk",
        "USAK0007" => "Aleknagik",
        "USAK0008" => "Allakaket",
        "USAL0028" => "Arlington",
        "USAL0029" => "Ashford",
        "USAL0030" => "Ashland",
        "USAL0031" => "Ashville",
        "USAL0032" => "Athens",
        "USAL0033" => "Atmore",
        "USAL0034" => "Attalla",
        "USAL0035" => "Auburn",
        "USAL0036" => "Auburn University",
        "USAL0037" => "Autaugaville",
        "USAL0038" => "Axis",
        "USAL0039" => "Baileyton",
       )
);
```

What I need to do is a search and replace to append the state name to the value, based on finding the two letter state abbreviation in the array key code.

So for example, a search that finds "AK" in the key and adds "Alaska" to the value, so they would look like this:

```
    "USAK0001" => "Alaska, Adak",
    "USAK0002" => "Alaska, Adak Island",
    "USAK0003" => "Alaska, Akiachak",
    "USAK0004" => "Alaska, Akiak",
    "USAK0005" => "Alaska, Akutan",
    "USAK0006" => "Alaska, Alakanuk",
```

Every key is 8 characters long, but I really don't even know how to begin trying to do this in Sublime Text.

Comment: Sublimetext enthusiasts might disagree, but wouldn't this task be solved much easier outside of the editor?

Comment: If you have an array of mapping from abbreviation to full name of the states, you can write a small PHP script to do the merging, then dump the content out for you to copy back to the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to nhahtdh, I did this quite easily with a PHP script to merge it.  It ended up being as simple as the below, with no need for regex! (Huzzah!)

```
function merge_states_into_cities( $states, $cities ) {

    foreach ( $cities as $key => $array ) {

        foreach ( $array as $code => $city ) {

            foreach ( $states as $abbrv => $state ) {

                if ( strpos( $code, $abbrv, 2 ) ) {
                    echo '"' . $code . '" => "' . $state . ', ' . $city . '",<br>';
                }

            }

        }
    }

}
```